# Is there a way to programmatically check if a Mac or PC keyboard is attached?

Tags: windows, io

Is there a way to reliably check programmatically if the keyboard attached to a computer is a Mac keyboard with Command (⌘) and option keys, or a PC keyboard with Windows, Alt, and Menu keys? For simplicity's sake assume that there is only one keyboard attached to the computer. An operating system independent solution would be best if there is one, but if you have to assume an OS, assume Windows 7.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you could figure out whether the F1 key is there, that would probably tell you. I believe that is missing by default on a Mac.

Comment: Mac keyboards have perfectly good F1 keys.

Answer (score 8):

Enumerate the attached USB devices and look for a keyboard. If you find one, and it's got a vendor id of 0x05AC (Apple Inc), then it's definitely an Apple keyboard. If the vendor is something else, or if you don't find any USB keyboards (e.g, the keyboard is probably hooked up via PS2), then it's probably not an Apple keyboard.

Comment: Apple laptop keyboards are internally attached via USB.

Comment: (This has since changed - some newer Apple laptops use SPI for keyboards. That being said, a laptop keyboard will necessarily be the same brand as the laptop.)

Comment: Older Apple keyboards are internally attached by ADB

Comment: Only on *very* old laptops. Even the first-generation Macbook laptops used a USB keyboard. I'm not sure about the early Macbook Pros, but honestly those are nearing obsolescence now.